# GET request from axios responding Network Error. Works with another URL, but not with this one

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I'm building a reactjs app that need to consume this API that I have not builded:
https://copafilmes.azurewebsites.net/api/filmes

When I access this URL from any browser or postman, I get the expected result, but when I try to consume in my app I get this error:
Error: "Network Error"
    createError createError.js:17
    handleError xhr.js:80

But when I try to access another URL from my reactjs app like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" it works normally.

Maybe the problem is on the API and not on my code?

```js
componentDidMount() {  
         axios.get('https://copafilmes.azurewebsites.net/api/filmes')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({
                movies: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you try adding parentheses to your res parameter? Like this:

         axios.get('https://copafilmes.azurewebsites.net/api/filmes')
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({
                movies: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })

Comment: Thanks for answering my question!
I just did that, but unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: When I run the code I get this error: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://copafilmes.azurewebsites.net/api/filmes' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

You need to edit the CORS configuration on the backend. Do you have access to the backend?

Comment: Hey @radihuq, I suspected this was the problem but my response was not as insightful as yours, how did you run to get this error?
And no, i don't have access to the backend, so theres not much I can do.

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome to debug. Are you using a different browser?